# Does Kumkumadi Lepana cure acne?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, acne

Is there peer reviewed evidence that looked at whether the [Kumkumadi Lepana](http://www.emporiumonnet.com/beauty_health/imis/Kumkumadi-Lepana-Acne.html) is an effective treatment for acne?

> Imis Kumkumadi Lepana Cream is widely used for removing black heads and pimples, and for having soft skin.
>
> Imis Kumkumadi Lepana :
>
> - Eradicates causative bacteria.
> - Brings glow to the skin.
> - Adds radiance to the skin.
> - Removes pimples, blemishes, scars and wrinkles.
> - Exerts antimicrobial, anti inflammatory anti oxidant properties.
> - Exhibits potent wound healing property.

Comment: Could you link to the source of the claim?

Comment: @Sklivvz I've rolled back your edit as the link is referenced in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Mayo clinic, the causes of acne are: Overproduction of oil, irregular shedding of dead skin cells and buildup of bacteria.  [Here is an overview](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/acne/DS00169/DSECTION=causes)

The reason why I actually wanted to post to this might not be to answer your question directly, but I did want to point out something about the link that you provided.  One of the listed ingredients is Mercurous chloride.  According to [this Material Safety Data Sheet](http://www.chemicalbook.com/CASEN_10112-91-1.htm#MaterialSafetyDataSheetMSDS) mercurous chloride :

> **Risk Statements**
>
> R22: Harmful if swallowed.
>   R36/37/38: Irritating to eyes, respiratory system and skin.
>   R50/53: Very Toxic to aquatic organisms, may cause long-term adverse effects in the aquatic environment.
>
> **Safety Statements**
>
> S13: Keep away from food, drink and animal feeding stuffs.
>   S24/25: Avoid contact with skin and eyes.
>   S46: If swallowed, seek medical advice immediately and show this container or label.
>   S60: This material and/or its container must be disposed of as hazardous waste.
>   S61: Avoid release to the environment. Refer to special instructions safety data sheet.

I know the dose makes the poison, but you may want to check into that before purchasing any.  In the meantime, try [some benzoyl peroxide or salycylic acid](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21691566)

Comment: I think it is [relevent](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/868/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-answer/874#874) to talk about safety: assuming that "effective treatment" includes "safe".

Comment: The same database has [a warning for salycylic acid](http://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductMSDSDetailCB1680010_EN.htm) (yes I know that it's a common ingredient in topic acne treatments): "Contact with skin causes irritation and possible burns, especially if the skin is wet or moist. If absorbed, may cause symptoms similar to those for ingestion. May cause skin rash and eruptions."